# Обработка пользовательского ввода С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

При обработке пользовательского вода никак не могу сделать проверку на ввод.
Вот, например, таким образом я запрещаю ввод символов и разрешаю ввод от 1 до 10, но при вводе цифр больше 10 или любого другого числа у меня происходит завершение программы. На выходе мне нужно именно `int` значение (сейчас пробую, но пока не получается что-то никак).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int x=0;
    while (!(cin >> x))
        {
            cin.clear();
            while (cin.get() != '\n');
            cout << "\tWrong digit try again!\n";
            cout << "\tEnter the second coordinate for the shot: ";
        }

result 0;
}
```

Comment: У вас переменная `x` даже не объявлена....

Comment: неужели компилятор вам ничего не сообщает?... или вы просто игнорируете его сообщения?

Comment: Всё объявлено, эта конструкция работает с буквами но если ввести цифры больше чем надо просто вылетает, мне надо от 1 до 10))) если ввожу больше он просто сразу завершает программу.

Comment: `result 0;` - что? И что значит "вылетает"? Программа просто завершается.

Answer (score 0):

Я не понимаю при чем тут ваш код к условию.

Если хотите получить число из введенной строки, просто считайте строку, а затем используйте std::atoi для получения целочисленного числа из строки.

Если хотите проверять введенный символ - используйте функцию isdigit.

Comment: Спасибо! буду пробовать!